# how can I enter a date restriction when using the Google Search API?

Tags: api, date

I'm wanting to use the Google Search API and find results based on the fact that they are only a day old. I can do this through the Google search engine but I can't seem to find a way to do this by using the API.

my code:
$googleFullURL = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=large&start=$searchIndex&lr=lang_en&filter=0&q=$searchTerms";

I tried using "&tbs=,qdr:d" at the end of my search which is what the search engine appends at the end of the URL when restricting to a date range but this seems to not be working.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the dateRestrict parameter which is a string.

> Restricts results to URLs based on date. Supported values include:
>
> - d[number]: requests results from the specified number of past days.
> - w[number]: requests results from the specified number of past weeks.
> - m[number]: requests results from the specified number of past months.
> - y[number]: requests results from the specified number of past years.

---

Documentation for parameters: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list