# Google CSE date range

Tags: date, date-range, google-custom-search

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798878/how-can-i-enter-a-date-restriction-when-using-the-google-search-api), but no solution given yet. I can find the "dateRestrict" parameter in the reference, but no parameter for date range similar to the one in the search protocol(e.g. daterange:2004-01-13..2006-01-13). There are highRange and lowRange in the reference, but te description is useless, it says: Specifies the ending/starting value for a search range.

I'd like to know if there are any parameter related to the date range.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It requires Julian dates format, eg daterange:2454833-2454863.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i am not sure what to do with it. I am interested in the parameter that is required in the REST request. "datarange" is a parameter that you can type when you search in the google web site.

Comment: In your webpage, the date you want to search must have doc date tag. eg <span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2013-10-19T10:42:08+08:00"> And In the query, customSearchControl.execute($("#searchkeyword").val() + ' daterange:2013-01-01..2013-10-01'); Actually, i find out that not need to be julian date. eg the key word you want to search is technology. customSearchControl.execute('technology daterange:2013-01-01..2013-10-01') where .. stand for range. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am sure it works, but i still use REST request from php. I build  the request url myself like this way: `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=<myKey-cut-from-here>&cx=<no-of-myCSE>&q=$swordFin&dateRestrict=$timeParam";` and then i work with the json string i get in return. Thanks for the effort anyway.